# How to return an Observable of type any from firebase query

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observable

I am using firebase realtime database for chat feature in my application, I just need to return an Obserable of type any or type Message from firebase query, 
Here is my code:

```
        getMessageHistory(farmerId) {

        let chatMessages = [];
        var chats;

        firebase.database().ref('/' + this.chatUrl + '/' + farmerId + '/').once('value', function (snapshot) {
            chats = snapshot.val();
            if (chats != null) {
                Object.keys(chats).forEach(element => {
                    let chat = chats[element.toString()];


                    var Message = {
                        fromId: chat.from,
                        toId: chat.to,
                        message: chat.message
                    }


                    let mockedHistory: Array<Message>;
                    mockedHistory.push(Message)
                });

            }
            else {
            }

        });
    }`
```

How do I return Observable from above method. I have tried angularfire2 but throwing an error while compiling (Angular Version 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution but I don't know is it recommended or not!

```
 let mockedHistory: Array<Message> = [];
    let totalRecords = this.db.list('/' + this.chatUrl + '/' + userId + '/');

    return totalRecords.valueChanges<any>().map((chat)=>{
        var newChat = chat.map((message) => {
            let msg = new Message();
            msg.fromId = message.from;
            msg.toId= message.to,
            msg.message= message.message
            return msg;
        });
        return newChat;
      }
    )
```